# update this quicksort algorithm to handle sorting on a specific key

Tags: php, algorithm, sorting

I believe that if you are dealing with completely jumbled sets of data, quicksort is one of the best ways of handling the sorting.  I would like to update the following code to handle arrays with keys so it can sort a list of arrays opposed to just the values in a single array.

```
function quicksort($array) {
    if (count($array) == 0)
            return array();

        $pivot = $array[0];
        $left = $right = array();

        for ($i = 1; $i < count($array); $i++) {
            if ($array[$i] < $pivot)
                $left[] = $array[$i];
            else
                $right[] = $array[$i];
        }
        return array_merge(self::quicksort($left, ''), array($pivot), self::quicksort($right, ''));
}
```

Comment: any good reason why you don't use [usort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)? it'll be fewer lines of code and a lot quicker!

Comment: usort is quicker on somewhat organized data, quicksort / heap sort  is supposed to be faster I thought... I'll find out once i get it to work with my arrays lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using a [usort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) with a [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

```
<?php
$arr = array(
    array("val" => 10, "something" => "zzz", "val2" => 1110),
    array("val" => 111, "something" => "aaa", "val2" => 1),
    array("val" => 1, "something" => "bbb", "val2" => 12),
    array("val" => 14, "something" => "eee", "val2" => 31),
    array("val" => 2, "something" => "ccc", "val2" => 11),
);

usort($arr, function ($a, $b) {
    if ($a['val2'] > $b['val2']) {
        $result = 1;
    } elseif ($a['val2'] < $b['val2']) {
        $result = -1;
    } else {
        $result = 0;
    }
    return $result;
});

var_dump($arr);
```

try thinking about a Sort Strategy Design Pattern

```
<?php
class SortStrategy
{
    public $key;

    public function __construct($key)
    {
        $this->key = $key;
    }

    public function cmp($a, $b)
    {
        return ($a[$this->key] > $b[$this->key]) ? 1 : (($a[$this->key] < $b[$this->key]) ? -1 : 0);
    }
}

$arr = array(
    array("val" => 10, "something" => "zzz", "val2" => 1110),
    array("val" => 111, "something" => "aaa", "val2" => 1),
    array("val" => 1, "something" => "bbb", "val2" => 12),
    array("val" => 14, "something" => "eee", "val2" => 31),
    array("val" => 2, "something" => "ccc", "val2" => 11),
);

// sort by val2 key
$objSortStrategy = new SortStrategy('val2');
usort($arr, [$objSortStrategy, 'cmp']);
var_dump($arr);

// sort by val key
$objSortStrategy->key = 'val';
usort($arr, [$objSortStrategy, 'cmp']);
var_dump($arr);

// sort by something key
$objSortStrategy->key = 'something';
usort($arr, [$objSortStrategy, 'cmp']);
var_dump($arr);
```

NOTE: this is just a quick example to give you some ideas

Comment: You skip a lot of the code using the PHP7 spaceship operator (if you're using PHP7 of course): `return $a['val2'] <=> $b['val2'];`

Answer (score 0):

OK SOLVED IT. I edited a quicksort and got it to work:

```
public static function quicksort($array, $key = '')
{
    if ($key) {
        if (count($array) == 0)
            return array();

        $pivot = $array[0];
        $left = $right = array();

        for ($i = 1; $i < count($array); $i++) {
            if ($array[$i][$key] < $pivot[$key])
                $left[] = $array[$i];
            else
                $right[] = $array[$i];
        }
        return array_merge(self::quicksort($left, $key), array($pivot), self::quicksort($right, $key));

    } else {

        if (count($array) == 0)
            return array();

        $pivot = $array[0];
        $left = $right = array();

        for ($i = 1; $i < count($array); $i++) {
            if ($array[$i] < $pivot)
                $left[] = $array[$i];
            else
                $right[] = $array[$i];
        }
        return array_merge(self::quicksort($left, ''), array($pivot), self::quicksort($right, ''));

    }
}
```

sample:

```
$qsort = new Algorithms();
$arr = array(
    array("val" => 10, "something" => "zzz", "val2" => 1110),
    array("val" => 111, "something" => "aaa", "val2" => 1),
    array("val" => 1, "something" => "bbb", "val2" => 12),
    array("val" => 14, "something" => "eee", "val2" => 31),
    array("val" => 2, "something" => "ccc", "val2" => 11),
);
var_dump($qsort->quicksort($arr,"val2"));
```